# azure AppInsights and third-party script CORS problem

Tags: javascript, cors, azure-application-insights

I have application insights enabled on my app website, and then have a third-party script loaded that communicates with its own website.

The problem is that app insights instruments the global XMLHttpRequest object, and when that script tries to fetch data from its own site it gets CORS error because it's sent actually from app insights (different origin).

How can I worka round the issue? Can I tell app insights not to instrument the XMLHttpRequest? (I don't really need it)

To clarify the the problem:

```html
<body>
...
<script>
// this instrumetns XMLHttpRequest
const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: {
    instrumentationKey: SOM_APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
  }
});
</script>
</body>

// this fails because XMLHttpRequest is instrumented (CORS error)
<script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.hs-scripts.com/XXX.js"></script>
</body>
```

The Error (in the latest Chrome browser):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://api.hubspot.com/livechat-public/v1/message/public?portalId=XXXXXXXX' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3333' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Request header field traceparent is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

(anonymous) @ InstrumentHooks.js:97       <<<<<< this is app insights code
f @ fetchWidgetData.js:78                 <<< this is third-party javascript
loadWidget @ WidgetShell.js:498
(anonymous) @ throttle.js:21
start @ WidgetShell.js:581
v @ startOnceReady.js:55
I @ startOnceReady.js:96
(anonymous) @ startOnceReady.js:111
captureErrors @ ErrorLogger.js:119
b @ startOnceReady.js:110
(anonymous) @ start.js:18
s @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:97
(anonymous) @ conversations-embed.js:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the solution [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/1905)

Basically the problem was caused by `traceparent` header sent by app insights. There is an option to disable that for specific third-party sites in app insights config, the `correlationHeaderExcludedDomains` option did the trick:

```
const insights = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: {
    instrumentationKey: ...
    correlationHeaderExcludedDomains: ['js.hs-scripts.com', 'api.hubspot.com'],
```

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to specify domains to include rather than exclude.  You can set that here `correlationHeaderDomains`.